# Корректно ли словосочетание "Вопросы на согласование"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Корректно ли словосочетание "Вопросы на согласование"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно в значении "вопросы на тему согласования": "Хочу задать вопрос на согласование времён" (вопрос по теме согласования). В деловом стиле есть штамп "вопрос на согласование":  "При возникновении вопроса на согласование перепланировки необходимо произвести ряд достаточно сложных действий" (вопрос в значении "проблема, задача").